# dbms_scheduler - Passing log_id in event based job

Tags: oracle, dbms-scheduler

I am trying to create an event based job using oracle dbms_scheduler as described below. Is there a way we can pass the job information that raised the event into the job that is executed based on that event.

Subscribing to the queue

```
BEGIN
   sys.DBMS_SCHEDULER.add_event_queue_subscriber ('my_queue_agent');
END;
```

Create program that will be called by the first job

```
begin
  sys.dbms_scheduler.create_program(program_name        => 'PROGRAM_TEST',
                                    program_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
                                    program_action      => 'PROC_TEST_SCHEDULER',
                                    number_of_arguments => 2,
                                    enabled             => false,
                                    comments            => '');
  sys.dbms_scheduler.define_program_argument(program_name        => 'PROGRAM_TEST',
                                             argument_position   => 1,
                                             argument_name       => 'P_JOB_NAME',
                                             argument_type       => 'VARCHAR2',
                                             default_value       => '');

  sys.dbms_scheduler.define_metadata_argument(program_name       => 'PROGRAM_TEST',
                                              metadata_attribute => 'LOG_ID',
                                              argument_position  => 2,
                                              argument_name      => 'LOG_ID');
  sys.dbms_scheduler.enable(name => 'PROGRAM_TEST');
end;
```

Create job that utilizes the program.

```
begin
  sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name            => 'TEST_PROGRAM_JOB',
                                program_name        => 'PROGRAM_TEST',
                                start_date          => to_date(null),
                                repeat_interval     => '',
                                end_date            => to_date(null),
                                job_class           => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
                                enabled             => false,
                                auto_drop           => false,
                                comments            => '');
  sys.dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value(job_name       => 'TEST_PROGRAM_JOB',
                                            argument_name  => 'P_JOB_NAME',
                                            argument_value => 'TEST_PROGRAM_JOB');

 sys.dbms_scheduler.set_attribute(name => 'TEST_PROGRAM_JOB', attribute => 'raise_events', value => sys.dbms_scheduler.job_started + sys.dbms_scheduler.job_succeeded + sys.dbms_scheduler.job_failed);
end;
```

Create second job that would be triggered based on events of first job.

```
BEGIN
   sys.DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
      job_name          => 'UPDATE_STATUS_JOB',
      job_type          => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
      job_action        => 'insert into t_log values (''UPDATE'' || tab.user_data.log_id,sysdate);',
      event_condition   => '(tab.user_data.event_type = ''JOB_SUCCEEDED'' OR 
                             tab.user_data.event_type = ''JOB_FAILED'' or
                             tab.user_data.event_type = ''JOB_STARTED'' or 
                             tab.user_data.event_type = ''JOB_COMPLETED'') AND tab.user_data.object_name = ''TEST_PROGRAM_JOB''',
      queue_spec        => 'sys.scheduler$_event_queue,my_queue_agent',
      enabled           => TRUE);
END;
```

Is there a way I can pass the current `log_id` of `TEST_PROGRAM_JOB` into `UPDATE_STATUS_JOB`? I want to log the status of the `TEST_PROGRAM_JOB`. Right now, I tried using `tab.user_data.log_id` but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

sys.dbms_scheduler.define_metadata_argument only works with 'job_name', 'job_subname', 'job_owner', 'job_start', 'window_start', 'window_end', and 'event_message.

In your case try to use event_message. You can also replace p_job_name with job_name.